# integral between cicular arcs above axis

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am trying to find the area of the red region in the picture. This region is bounded by two circular arcs, $A$ and $B$, and the axis. $A$ is tangent to the axis, which I mention in case it simplifies the problem at all.

My first idea was to solve this by integrating the area under each arc separately and take the difference. However, this has been less straightforward than I had hoped. Any suggestions on how to approach finding the area of the red region?

[image]

Comment: You should solve the equation of each curve for $x$ in terms of $y$, find the $y$-coordinate $b$ of the intersection, then find $A=\int_0^bx_2(y)-x_1(y)\,dy$.

Comment: Go to polar coordinates.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales My bad, you are right.  I am therefore going to delete my answer.

Comment: Initially, I disagreed with the comment of John Wayland Bales, and posted an answer accordingly.  Then he pointed out my mistake; I was misinterpreting his comment, which suggests integrating with respect to $y$ rather than $x$.  I therefore deleted my answer.